# Reference to array of struct

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++, struct

I am learning about references in C++. Is it not possible to create a reference to an array of structs?

```
struct student {
    char name[20];
    char address[50];
    char id_no[10];
};

int main() {
    student test;
    student addressbook[100];
    student &test = addressbook; //This does not work
}
```

I get the following errors:

> a reference of type "student &" (not const-qualified) cannot be initialized with a value of type "student [100]"
>   Error   C2440   'initializing': cannot convert from 'student [100]' to 'student &'

Comment: The type of addressbook is not `student`, it's `student[100]`. And you don't want to learn to make references to an array. Just use a pointer/iterator.

Answer (score 5):

The type of the reference must match what it is referring to . A reference to a single student cannot refer to an array of 100 students.  Your options include:

```
// Refer to single student
student &test = addressbook[0];

// Refer to all students
student (&all)[100] = addressbook;
auto &all = addressbook;               // equivalent
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes it's possible. It just has to be a reference of the right type. A student is not an array of 100 students. The syntax is a bit awkward though:

```
student (&test)[100] = addressbook;
```

It will make more sense once you read this: http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html

The most common place you'll see array references is probably as arguments to template functions, where the size is deduced.

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
void foo(T (&arr)[N]);
```

This allows you to pass an array to a function as a single argument without it decaying to a pointer and losing size information.

An example of this can be seen in the standard library with `std::begin/end`.